# How can I create a Batch script that can create a .jar file from a set of stubs?

Tags: batch-file, jar

I have found myself on the command line redundantly typing the same “create a jar file from stubs” commands over and over.

How can I create a Batch script that can create a .jar file from a set of Web service stubs to save me from this redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

The below steps will help anyone trying to do this if BATCH scripts are supported.

**Step 1:**

Open your favorite text editor.

**Step 2:**

Copy and paste the below into your text editor.

```
echo "Starting .jar file creation process"

cd C:\stubs\YourStubFileDirectory

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\jar" -cvf NameYourJar.jar C:\stubs\YourStubFileDirectory \com\yourdomain\etc\axis\packagename

echo "Jar File Created...  Please exit.  "
```

**Step 3:**

Change the paths to meet your paths (path to your stub file directory, your package name, etc...) and change to your version of Java.

**Step 4:**

Save your file.  Name it what you'd like but add the .bat extension at the end to form a "BATCH" file.

e.g.(myJarCreator.bat).

**Step 5:**

Double click your .bat file and it will execute for you; creating the .jar you want from your stubs.